# how to do the completed data to stay when I switch to another component using Angular5. Not with localstorage

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a InvoicSaleComponent, in this invoice I can input some details, like client, date, note and Products. For add product I can navigate in other ProductsComponent, when I add product I can return in invoice.

Firstly fill out the detail of invoice, like client name, date, note, and then add the products. When I click for add a product my details in invoice are deleted. Any idea how to stay my detail?

Invoice Sale Component:

```
<form [formGroup]="addsale" (ngSubmit)="onaddsale()" class="col s12" materialize>
  <!-- Header invoice-->
  <div class="contant">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <div class="row">
          Date:
          <input formControlName="invoice_date" id="invoice_date" type="date" class="datepicker" materialize="pickadate" [materializeParams]="[{ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          closeOnSelect: true, selectMonths: true, selectYears: true, today: '',
          max: true, onSet: onSetDatepicker }]">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
      Client:
        <input formControlName="client" id="client" type="text" class="validate">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        Notes:
        <input formControlName="notes" id="notes" type="text" class="validate">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- Body invoice-->
  <table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr style="color:black;">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>No. Serial</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products">
        <td>{{getProductTName(item.p_Product_type_id)}}</td>
        <td>{{getProductName(item.p_product_id)}}</td>
        <td>{{item.p_Unit_price}}</td>
        <td> {{item.p_Quantity}} </td>
        <td>{{item.p_Description}} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
   <div class="action-btn">
    <a routerLink="/addproduct" class="waves-yellow btn btn-lg btn-yellow">
     Add Product
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Invoice Sale Component .ts

```
products: Array<Products>;

  this.addsale = this.fb.group({
      'invoice_date': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'client': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'notes': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'products': this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.products = this.ps.getProduct();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: you could start looking at formgroups

Comment: when you navigate from a component to another the variables of the first component are erased. So, before you navigate to another component you need store the variables in anything. You can use a service. A service is manteined along the live of the application. It's know as "shared" service that is simply a service with a variable